# Return dates (not strings) from an ADODB query

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

The function below works fine and outputs the correct result except it outputs the dates as strings and not as dates. How can I get it to output dates instead?

```
Function GetExpiries_YieldX(TradeDate As Date, Code As String) As Variant

    'Create and open the connection
    Dim oConnection As Connection
    Set oConnection = New Connection
    oConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionStringYieldX
    oConnection.Open

    'Create the command object
    Dim oCommand As Command
    Set oCommand = New Command
    oCommand.CommandType = adCmdText

    Dim SQLString As String

        SQLString = "SELECT DISTINCT Expiry" _
                 & " FROM MTM" _
                 & " WHERE TradeDate = ?" _
                 & "   and Code = ?"

    oCommand.CommandText = SQLString
    oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection

    oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("Date", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
    oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("Code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)

    oCommand.Parameters.Item("Date").Value = TradeDate
    oCommand.Parameters.Item("Code").Value = Code

    Dim result As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set result = oCommand.Execute

    Dim resultA As Variant
    'GetExpiries_YieldX = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.GetRows)
    GetExpiries_YieldX = result.GetRows

    oConnection.Close

End Function
```

Comment: is the column **Expiry** in the database defined as DataTime?

Comment: what are you doing with the resultset? If putting into a worksheet range, you could just dump the recordset into a range using **Range(..).CopyFromRecordset** method, then modify the format of those range using NumberFormat

Comment: @Philip no it's just `date` type (SQL Server 2008 btw), I am putting the dates on the worksheet. At the moment I'm just converting them to dates doing this sort of thing: `=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),RIGHT(A2,2))` but I would prefer if they just came out as dates if possible. I find it very difficult to find decent documentation on how to write these sort of functions (i.e. vba functions that query sql server dbs) properly :/

Comment: or you could try casting the Expiry field into a date format in your SQL string: "SELECT DISTINCT CDATE(Expiry)...

Comment: casting just returns #VALUES...

Comment: @aardvark123 I think you mean *"SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Expiry as datetime) from table* ?

Comment: @Dan, how are you putting the data in your variant into the worksheet please? And can you give us an example of the data value (not text) that ends up in the cells

Comment: @Philip I'm putting the data in the worksheet as an array function, so I'm selecting 4 cells pressing F2 typing in `=GetExpiries_YieldX($A$1,$B$1)` (where `A1` holds a date and `B1` an appropriate string) and then Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Not sure what you mean by the output but it comes out as a string just like it would in sql server so `2013-06-14` for example.

Comment: and if it looks like `2013-06-14` in Excel, what do you want it to look like? Can't you set the cells NumberFormat property to change the way it looks?

Comment: @Philip No I can't because it's a string, not a date. That's why `=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,6,2),RIGHT(A2,2))` works. But actually it looks like I can still pass the cells to formulae expecting dates, I just can't format them. Maybe I can just add zero to all the dates inside the function or something. Anyway, the formula I posted is a fine work around, it just seems unnecessary, like I'm not writing the vba function correctly.

Comment: after the **result** is populated with a recordset, perhaps you could test the following: msgbox result.fields(0).type to see if it is = 7 (`adDate`) datatype.

Comment: I get `202`, not `7` :/ but also it brings up the msgbox twice for some reason?

Comment: ah ha ! Type = 202 is **adVarWChar** so the ADO recordset has the column set to NOT DATE ! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADODB versions prior to 2.8 had  aproblem recognizing the new **Date** datatype introduced in SQL Server 2008.

So, check the following:

1. Ensure you are using the *native* SQL Server Provider (**NOT OLEDB SQL provider**) in your Connnection string, so it should be something like *"Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Uid=MyUser;Pwd=MyPassword;"*
2. Make sure you've installed latest SQL Native Client (sqlncli2008.msi or something like that, you can steal it from SQL Server 2008 redistributable)
3. Ensure ADO version referenced in your VB Project is 2.8

found all that on [ADODB & SQL 2008 (MS Forums)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/0669b633-94e0-4ee3-8785-3e53599bf09c/)

I hope that helps you get a Date column in your array from a Date column in your db!

Comment: Just changing the connection string (i.e. step 1 n your answer) fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome, it was fun going back and forth to work out what was going on :)