# UDF to retrieve data from access data base

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, bloomberg

How do i create a UDF to retrieve data from the access database.

I can retrieve the data via sql query using vba & click button. the data will be in the recordset. I simply paste it to any cell.

Now my question is: How can I create a user defined function to do the same. That is to say, when I enter something like `=bdh(pricing date,product tag)` into any Excel cell, all the data will be returned and pasted below the cell where I entered the self-defined formula.

If you are familiar with bloomberg API, i want to build a function similar to `bdh` function.

Comment: Hi Jack, I fairly certain that that is impossible to do via a UDF. A function cannot alter any cells outside of the cells selected. Your best bet is to return a recordset as an array function. Bloomberg has a data service that watches Excel and it is the data service rather than the function that places the extra data in the cells below. As I understand it, this is an extremely difficult process to implement. You could produce some sort of hack I guess by implementing a clever cell change event, but I doubt it's worth it.

Comment: BTW some questions that show examples of how to write an array function that returns a record set (from SQL, but I think you could just change the provider in the connection string to get Access): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927485/return-dates-not-strings-from-an-adodb-query or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597485/using-the-same-parameter-twice

Comment: Hi. Dan. Your help is very appreciated. My boss said i could possibly do it via some sort of array function. Is that true? Are you saying that there is no way to paste the data below the cell where i entered my own BDH function without the hack like any event change.Thanks.

Comment: someone suggests to use the Ctrl+Shift+Enter. I am still struggling to find out the solution. =)

Comment: there is no way. You can do it with an array formula but that requires you to select all the cells you wish to output to BEFORE typing the function. So if you don't know how many rows to expect then you have to guess. I normally just select way more rows than the query could possibly return.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter is for an array formula, it's no where near as nice as the way bloomberg does it but it is pretty good. That's how I do it. See the links I posted above for example code. But also you could just make a data table connection straight to access, have you tried that? http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/excel-help/connect-an-access-database-to-your-workbook-HA102840045.aspx

Comment: The end user is the market risk analyst who need to use the function in the same way as BHD function which they are currently using. The number of data could be of hundreds of thousands lines. =(

Comment: I am trying to make it as user-friendly as possible.

Comment: well you can't unless you want to learn how to implement a data service, but since array formulae seem new to you I would say that that probably isn't an option for you.

Comment: Hi Dan. Are you there?

Comment: I think your question is addressed in the following thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408630/excel-vba-user-defined-function-to-query-an-access-database

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could work around a simpler idea? For example the code snippet below depends on the user selecting two input cells to control the output. You could add a menu item to run the code.

```
Sub GetMSAccess()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim selrange As Range

    Set selrange = Selection

    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb"

    cn.Open strCon

    sSQL = "SELECT var1, var2 FROM table2 " _
    & "WHERE var1='" & selrange.Cells(1, 1).Value _
    & "' AND var2=" & selrange.Cells(1, 2).Value
    rs.Open sSQL, cn

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

For example

[image: select cells]